# VSCode with rmate command not found with raspberry pi

Tags: visual-studio-code, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to edit a simple python file remotely on my raspberry pi. In visual studio code, I hit `Ctrl+Shift+P`, type `Remote: Start Server`, and hit `enter`. I see `Starting Server` in the lower left portion of my screen. Next, I connect to my raspberry pi using

`ssh -R ssh -R 52698:localhost:52698 pi@PI_NAME`

I navigate to the python file I want to edit and type

`rmate test.py`

And I get the error

`-bash: rmate: command not found`

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I tried searching for a solution, but nobody else has this specific problem as far as I can tell. In the usage section on the [Remote VSCode site](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rafaelmaiolla.remote-vscode), it says to take the steps that I took above.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
ssh -R 52698:127.0.0.1:52698 pi@PI_NAME
```

If you didn't install rmate in your RPI, try below

```
sudo wget -O /usr/local/bin/rmate https://raw.github.com/aurora/rmate/master/rmate
sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/rmate
```